# Rename file after upload really finished in linux

Tags: linux, bash, sftp

I have to upload large files to the sftp server and after the upload is finished, rename the files (basically add .ready extension) so that I can mark this as uploaded and ready for further processing.

I have seen that fuser  can show if the file is still reserved by process.

Have someone faced similar problems and maybe have soem script available?

Update: I can test this in my own environment, two servers with full access. Problem is that in the live env, I don't have access to client side. But maybe I can give instructions or script to be run using cron...

I already tried lftp, but I was not able to rename the file with the command.

```
lftp sftp://sftpuser:Test#1234@10.9.220.220 -e "put test;bye"
```

Comment: Hi, Which language are you using? Which program to upload (if any?)

Comment: Why not just use a script that does the upload and rename?

Comment: SFTP server is running rhel 6.6 and openssh-clients-5.3p1-104.el6.x86_64. I have made sftp jail to sftpuser in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. SFTP client is also rhel server.

Comment: Do you want to rename the local source file or remote destination file?

Comment: Destination file after sftp transfer is finished.

Comment: I note that `put test; bye` isn't **trying** to do a rename. If you're going to say that something doesn't work, it would be helpful to show code that actually attempts to do that thing, and describe any errors &c. resulting.

Comment: (That said -- do you mean to be doing a *local* rename or a *remote* rename?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sftp` to rename the file on the remote, assuming `sftp` can authenticate you in batch mode, i.e. through `ssh-agent`.

```
$ file=foo.txt
$ echo -e "put $file\nrename $file $file.ready\n" | \
   sftp -b - user@somehost
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with sftp's [batch mode](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/sftp1.html) and Bash's [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

```
sftp -b <(echo put file) server:dir/ && mv file file.ready
```

Do not write passwords in shell scripts!

https://askubuntu.com/questions/4830/easiest-way-to-copy-ssh-keys-to-another-machine

Comment: Thanks all. I tried ceving's idea and this what happened. I think it has something to do with the sftp jail in /Data0/sftpuser/incoming
 directory. sftp -b <(echo put test) 10.9.220.220:incoming/ && mv test test.ready
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer

Comment: @saho make sure that `sftp` works, before you start using the batch mode. Typically you have to transfer your public SSH key to the remote machine.

Comment: In most cases, you will at least need to add username to the command: `sftp -b <(echo put test) username@10.9.220.220:...`

Comment: Hi, manually sftp work fine. sftp sftpuser@10.9.220.220
Connecting to 10.9.220.220...
sftpuser@10.9.220.220's password: 
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /incoming
sftp> put test
Uploading test to /incoming/test
test                                                                     100% 1024MB 113.8MB/s   00:09    
sftp>

Comment: Cevin, good point not to write passwords in scripts. I just created and copied sshs key. But like Martin already asked, I am trying to rename the files in the dest folder. I tried your proposal with root account and it worked fine, but changed the file name in the source folder. Good tip anyway.

Comment: Why do you process-substitute `<(echo put file)`, when (since you require Bash anyway), you could simply provide a here-string `<<<'put file'`?

Comment: @TobySpeight If you add a `-b -` that might be an alternative.